# Alfresco Forum not allowing me to post new topic

Tags: alfresco

I just created a new ID in the Alfresco Forum (forums.alfresco.com)
but it won't let me post new content.
Has anyone else had this problem?
Does anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: It may be because it is under review. Have you tried after some time?

Comment: It has been a few weeks.

Comment: That's not a question related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, due to the spam load on the forums, alfresco is revoking -temporarly- posting permission from new accounts, in order to reduce the amount of spam posted to the forums.

In order to get your account verfied with posting privileges, you should either contact alfresco on `community[at]alfresco[dot]com` or post a reply to [this thread](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/general/announcements/having-trouble-posting-new-topics-01122016-2132).